# Is there a way to map a multi-variable structure onto a single range?

Tags: mathematical-programming

I want to categorise variants of a structure made up of some number of variable components by mapping it to a unique range. Assume that the individual components all fall within the same base range.

I'm using color as an example for this question as its intuitive to think about but I don't want the question to be specific to that, its just a framework for understanding the problem.

### Simple case:

Imagine I have a structure, called `C` made up of two values `(r, b)` (red and blue) and I want to categorise variants of `C` into distinct bands, things like "very red", "quite blue", "slightly blue", "quite red" etc.

In this case I could just map the values by starting at `0` and then adding anything in the `r` channel and subtracting anything in the `b` channel, then I would get a final value in a 1 dimensional range somewhere between `-1` and `1` (assuming the values for `r` and `b` are clamped. Then I could use this output value to categorise it into a band: maybe anything below `-0.8` is "very blue" and a value between `0.4` and `0.5` is "somewhat red".

Examples:

`(0.1, 0.3)` `->` `-0.2`

`(1.0, 0.0)` `->` `1.0`

`(0.2, 0.9)` `->` `-0.7`

### Not so simple:

However, if I introduce a third value, so `C` is made up of `(r, b, g)`, I can't see how I can easily map this to a range which I can make assertions about, like "bluey green" or "reddish blue". Trying to create a solution in code for this (naively) just ends with a complicated set of conditional statements.

One solution I thought might work would be to convert the 3D version of `C` into a point on a triangle expressed as a weighting of its vertices (where each vertex corresponds to one of `C`'s components), and then convert that point in 2D coordinate space into a categorisation based on where it falls in a sub-shape - which is just a delimited area - on the triangle. So I could say, if the point falls inside this sub-shape on the triangle its "bluey green", if the point falls inside this other sub-shape, then its "reddish blue" etc. However, this does seems like a fairly intricate solution and I'm not sure if I am heading down the wrong path.

Also, I can't see how this would then generalise to putting more and more variables into `C`.

I don't a have strong intuition for what field of mathematics or computer science I should be looking into to solve a problem like this or how exactly mapping like this work.

**If anyone knows how to solve this** or **what sort of things I should be looking at to solve it**, I would really appreciate some advice! Thanks.

Comment: So many words and so little useful/concrete information. How many values can take each dimension? If the values in each dimension are bounded by $N$, say $0,1,2,\ldots,N-1$, you can use a map like a positional system $(r,g,b)\mapsto b+N\cdot g+N^2\cdot r$. Are there any other conditions that the map should satisfy? Less practical, but without a bound you can map as in Godel's code $(r,g,b)\mapsto 2^r\cdot 3^g\cdot 5^b$. The inverse of an approximation to a [space filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) can also give a map.

Comment: What properties do you insist/require/want the mapping to have?  There are many possible mappings, and I suspect you won't be happy with most of them, but you haven't listed your requirements.  Do you really want to put them onto a single dimension, or can you map them to a multi-dimensional space?  Is your ultimate goal categorization (to combine them into a few groups), rather than to obtain a continuous number for each?

Comment: It sounds less like OP really wants a space-filling curve, and more like he wants to do (multi-class) classification. If the classes are seperated by hyperplanes, then in effect, yes OP ends up with what is basically a bunch of conditional statements. This is equivalent to his triangle/convex shape idea, this in effect also is a bunch of conditional statements. He wants to map his values so he can use simple conditions, but space-filling curves won't get him that, I fear.

Comment: @plop Apologies if the information isn't clear. I'm not very experienced in these things :( I'll try and reiterate what I want more clearly below.

Comment: @D.W. I think the mapping can be a multi-dimensional space. Although, I'm not 100% sure what that would mean. Basically the values always come through in a range from `0.0-1.0` and I just wanted to know if there's a simple way I can categorise different ranges, like, any variant where all the values for `(r, b, g)` are less than `0.1` would be "dark black", or any variant that has `r > 0.8` and `b < 0.1` and `g > 0.8` would be "bright pink". I'm looking for a mapping that makes these kinds of conditionals easier. (cont)

Comment: Because, if you look at a color picker you can see that there are lots of possibilities around a color space that are all in the same area on that 2D plane, but expressing them as conditional statements using `>` and `<` for the three variable components makes that really complicated. So I kind of have the intuition that there must be some way to express that I just want categorise this sort of color space in some way based on where values are grouped, but I can't really see how I might do that. I apologise if it's not clear.

Comment: @kutschkem I think you expressed it the best. I'll try and look up the things you mentioned.

Comment: Theoretically, there are no open (i.e. continuous inverse) injective maps from $[0,1]^3$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: @plop ok... so maybe its not easy to do then. What is the significance of the notation $[0,1]^3$?

Comment: @OPKD It means triples (a, b, c) where a, b and c all are in the range [0,1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve this for colors, there are many techniques that are appropriate in that domain.  But you say you aren't really asking about colors, so I'll treat it as an analogy and try to give an answer that is more general (but wouldn't be what I would recommend for colors):

It sounds like you want to cluster the possible values into multiple clusters.  I would suggest you read about [clustering algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). You'll need to pick a "similarity measure" that measures how similar two structures are.  That is domain-specific and not something we can tell you; you'll have to pick it based on your knowledge of the specific application domain.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this looks promising, I will have a read and see if I can figure out a solution!